# Grunt error running default task

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have just started with Grunt and I keep getting this error. 
**Reference error: model is not not defined.**

Possibly something wrong with my config? I followed these steps.

1. Installed grunt-cli globally with **npm install -g grunt-cli**
2. Installed grunt to local directory with npm install grunt
3. Created this Gruntfile.js in local directory.
4. Run -> grunt default -v

My Gruntfile.js

```
    model.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.registerTask("default", function () {
        grunt.log.writelne("Hello world");
      });
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is indicating the `model` variable is undefined in your Gruntfile.js. The proper variable in this instance is `module`. There's also a typo in `grunt.log.writelne`.

So, the correct format would be

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.registerTask("default", function () {
        grunt.log.writeln("Hello world");
    });
};
```

You can view the [Sample Gruntfile.js](http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile) in the Grunt.js reference docs for the general format.

Comment: Thanks - its always the obvious stuff